# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method move() from the type Monstro

Tags: java

По информатике нам задали сделать игру и я очень часто встречаюсь с такой ошибкой.

- Monstro (Монстр)
- BadGuy (Плохой парень) он расширяет класс Монстр
- Hero (Герой)

Класс Монстра:

```
    package pt.iul.ista.poo.example;
    import java.util.List;
    import pt.iul.ista.poo.gui.ImageTile;
    import pt.iul.ista.poo.rogue.utils.Position;
    import pt.iul.ista.poo.rogue.utils.Vector2D;

    public class Monstro extends GameObjects {

        public Monstro (Position position, String name) {
           super(position, name);
        }

    public void move (Hero hero) {

    double r = Math.random();

    System.out.println(r);

    int Hx = hero.getPosition().getX();
    int Hy = hero.getPosition().getY();

    Position M = super.getPosition();
    int Mx = super.getPosition().getX();
    int My = super.getPosition().getY();

    int Dx = Hx - Mx;
    int Dy = Hy - My;

    if(Dx <= 2 && Dy <= 2 || Dx >= -2 && Dy >= -2){

    } else {
        if (0 < r && r <= 0.25) {
            //cima (0,-1)
            M = new Position(Mx,My-1);
        }
        if (0.25 < r && r <= 0.50) {
            //esquerda (-1,0)
            M = new Position(Mx-1,My);
        }
        if (0.50 < r && r<= 0.75) {
            //baixo (0,1)
            M = new Position(Mx,My+1);
        }
        if (0.75 < r && r <= 1) {
            //direito (1,0)
            M = new Position(Mx+1,My);
        }
    }


    Position positionNext = M;

    int x = positionNext.getX();
    int y = positionNext.getY();

    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > 9 || y > 9)
        return;

    List<ImageTile> tiles = Engine.getInstance().getSelectedRoom().getTiles();

    for (ImageTile a: tiles) {

        if(a.getName().equals("Wall") && positionNext.equals(a.getPosition())) {

            System.out.println(positionNext);

        } else {
            super.setPosition(positionNext);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Класс Героя:

```
    package pt.iul.ista.poo.example;

    import java.util.List;
    import pt.iul.ista.poo.gui.ImageTile;
    import pt.iul.ista.poo.rogue.utils.Position;
    import pt.iul.ista.poo.rogue.utils.Vector2D;

    public class Hero extends GameObjects{

    private Room room;

public Hero(Position position) {
    super (position, "Hero");
}

public void move (Vector2D s) {

    Position z = super.getPosition();
    Position positionNext = super.getPosition().plus(s);

    int x = positionNext.getX();
    int y = positionNext.getY();

    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > 9 || y > 9)
        return;

    List<ImageTile> tiles = Engine.getInstance().getSelectedRoom().getTiles();

    for (ImageTile a: tiles) {

        if(a.getName().equals("Wall") &&                     positionNext.equals(a.getPosition()))
            positionNext = z;

    // System.out.println(positionNext);
        else {
            super.setPosition(positionNext);
        }
    }
}

public void setRoom(Room room) {
    this.room = room;
}
```

}

Класс Плохого Парня:

```
package pt.iul.ista.poo.example;

import pt.iul.ista.poo.rogue.utils.Position;

public class BadGuy extends Monstro {

    public BadGuy(Position position) {
        super (position, "BadGuy");
    }


    public void movement(){

        BadGuy.move(null); // Здесь пишет проблему которая находить в заголовке

    }

}
```

Код сделан для того что бы герой и плохой парень двигались. Так как у меня будет много монстров (а плохой парень это один из них) я решил сделать класс в котором будет код для того что бы монстр двигался и прибегать к нему когда будет нужно.

Любая критика кода приветствуеться

Comment: Что за ошибка то? Скинь стек ошибок (текст ошибок. можешь скопировать его в LogCat - напиши в яндексе "logcat как пользоваться")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BadGuy.move(null);` - подобной записью ты пытаешься вызвать статический метод класса `BagGuy`, хотя такого у тебя в классе или в суперклассе не существует, однако имеется нестатический в предке.

Если ты все-таки хочешь обратиться к методу, то создавай экземпляр класса `BadGuy`, чтобы относительно него вызвать метод `move()`.

```
BadGay badGay = new BadGay(...);
badGay.move(...);
```

P.S Подобной записью ты нарываешься напасть на **NullPointerException**

```
.move(null);
```